# Swift 3 / IQKeyboardManager : How do you change background color of toolbar , done color, arrow colors?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, iqkeyboardmanager

How do you change background color of toolbar , done color, arrow colors, and hide the text title on the toolbar in the middle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the appearance of `Next`/`Previous`(arrow) and `Done` buttons color by setting `tintColor` of the toolbar using below code.

**To change arrow and done button colors to red:**

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarTintColor = .red
```

**To hide text title on the toolbar in the middle**

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
```

I haven't find any property to change bar color but can change background color of `IQToolbar` class itself.
If you find any, then add here for other's reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.toolbarBarTintColor = .red
```

This is changing the toolbar bg color. 
It is actually quite easy to understand just by reading IQKeyboardManager code comments ( if you first familiar with UIKit itself)